# How to remove the space under footer?

Tags: html, css

Please help!

I tried many tricks to remove the white space under my footer but none of them solved my problem. I noticed that the white space is only visible in the pages with *text, p and h1* tags. Any help is highly appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Olive Green Studio</title>
<link href="oliva.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!—[if lt IE 7]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6.css" />
<![endif]—>
<!--[if IE 5]>
<style type="text/css"> 
/* place css box model fixes for IE 5* in this conditional comment */
.twoColFixLtHdr #sidebar1 { width: 230px; }
</style>
<![endif]--><!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css"> 
/* place css fixes for all versions of IE in this conditional comment */
.twoColFixLtHdr #sidebar1 { padding-top: 30px; }
.twoColFixLtHdr #mainContent { zoom: 1; }
/* the above proprietary zoom property gives IE the hasLayout it needs to avoid several bugs */
</style>
<![endif]--></head>

<body class="twoColFixLtHdr">

<div id="container">
  <div id="header"><!-- end #header -->
    <div id="logo">
    <a href="index.html">
    <img src="olivaimages/olivegreenlogoweb.png" border="none"/>
    </a>
  </div>
   <div id="sidebar1">

<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
  <!-- end #sidebar1 --></div>


  </div>
  <div id="mainContent">
<h1>Contact Us </h1>
<p>If you need a creative help or want to take your project to the next level please don't hesitate to drop us a line.</p>
<a class="worklinks" href= "mailto:info@olivegreenstudio.com"> info@olivegreenstudio.com</a>   
  <!-- end #mainContent --></div>
    <!-- This clearing element should immediately follow the #mainContent div in order to force the #container div to contain all child floats --><br class="clearfloat" />
   <div class="clearfooter"></div>

  <!-- end #container -->
</div>

          <div id="footerframe">
<div id="footer">
            <div id="footer2">
            <div id="address">Khobar<br> Saudi Arabia </div>
            <div id="contact">
            <strong>Services:</strong><br> Logos<br>Branding<br>Identity<br>Collaterals<br>Packaging<br> Web Design & Development <br>
           </div>
          <div id="email">
            If you have a project inquiry, we will be happy to answer you <a class="contactlink" href="mailto:info@olivegreenstudio.com"> here.</a>
 </div>

<div class="social">
            <div class="twitter">
            <a href="https://twitter.com/OliveGreenSTU" />
            <img src="olivaimages/twitterbirdwebgreen.png" onmouseover="this.src='olivaimages/twitterbirdweb-lightgreen.png'" onmouseout="this.src='olivaimages/twitterbirdwebgreen.png'" />
            </div>
            </a>

               <div id="pinterest">
               <a href="http://pinterest.com/olivegreenstu/">
               <img src="olivaimages/pinterestwebgreen.png" onmouseover="this.src='olivaimages/pinterestweb-lightgreen.png'"   
onmouseout="this.src='olivaimages/pinterestwebgreen.png'" />
   </a>
             </div>
     <div class="copywrite"> © 2013 Olive Green. All rights reserved.</div> 
  </div>   

</div>
     </div>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
  @charset "UTF-8";
    body  {
        margin: 0; /* it's good practice to zero the margin and padding of the body element to account for differing browser defaults */
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 100%;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .twoColFixLtHdr #header {
        height: 170px;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0;
    } 
    h1 {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: #5A6219;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
    h2 {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #908B23;
        text-decoration: none;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    p {
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-style: normal;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #908B23;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    .twoColFixLtHdr #container {
        width: 900px;
        text-align: left; /* this overrides the text-align: center on the body element. */
        min-height: 100%;
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        position: relative;
        margin-bottom: -215px;
        height: 100%;
    } 
    .twoColFixLtHdr #mainContent {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #FFF;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        border-top-width: 1px;
        border-top-style: solid;
        border-top-color: #CCC;
        padding-top: 50px;
        padding-bottom: 70px;
    } 
    .workmaincontent {
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #FFF;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        border-top-width: 1px;
        border-top-style: solid;
        border-top-color: #CCC;
        padding-top: 50px;
        padding-bottom: 70px;
    }
    .fltrt { /* this class can be used to float an element right in your page. The floated element must precede the element it should be next to on the page. */
        float: right;
        margin-left: 8px;
    }
    .fltlft { /* this class can be used to float an element left in your page */
        float: left;
        margin-right: 8px;
    }
    .clearfloat { /* this class should be placed on a div or break element and should be the final element before the close of a container that should fully contain a float */
        clear:both;
        height:0;
        font-size: 1px;
        line-height: 0px;
    }
    .twoColFixLtHdr #sidebar1 {
        float: right; /* since this element is floated, a width must be given */
        width: 300px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        margin-top: 70px;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        height: 30px;
    }

    #sidebar1 {
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        height: 200px;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding-right: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        width: 500px;
    }
    #sidebar1 ul {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    #sidebar1 li {
        display: run-in;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    #sidebar1 a {
        display: run-in;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #918C10;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        padding: 5px;
        float: left;
        width: 65px;
    }
    #sidebar1 a:hover {
        color: #5A6219;
    }

    .worklinks{
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #5A6219;
        text-decoration: none;

    }

    .worklinks:hover{
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #908B23;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    #print{
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #FFF;
        width: 730px;
        float: left;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        margin-left: 85px;
        margin-right: 85px;
    }

    #web{
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #FFF;
        width: 730px;
        float: left;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        margin-left: 85px;
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
    #packaging{
        background-color: #FFF;
        height: 100%;
        width: 730px;
        float: left;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        margin-left: 85px;
    }
    .imagetitles a {
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: "Century Gothic";
        font-size: 25px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #00CCCC;
    }
    #printtitle{
        bottom: -5px;
        left: 333px;
    }
    #webtitle{
        position: absolute;
        left: 333px;
        top: 521px;
    }
    #packagingtitle{
        position: absolute;
        left: 317px;
        top: 823px;
        width: 89px;
    }

    #bigimages{
        width: 570px;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .imagestalk {
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #666666;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }


    .thumbnails {
        border: 5px solid #666666;
    }
    h3 {
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-style: normal;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #5A6219;
        text-decoration: none;
    }


    h3 a:link {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #000000;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    h3 a:visited {
        color: #D0BA0B;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    h3 a:hover {
        color: #5A6219;
    }
    h3 a:active {
        color: #579835;
    }

    .back{
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #666666;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding-left: 520px;
    }
    .back a:link {
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #666666;
    }
    .back a:visited {
        color: #666666;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .back a:hover {
        color: #000000;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .back a:active {
        color: #333333;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .source{
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #666666;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .workimage {
        height: 150px;
        width: 200px;
        float: left;
        margin: 20px;
    }

    img {
    border: 0;
    }

    #logo {
        height: 150px;
        width: 300px;
        float: left;
    }
    #footerframe {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #AEA03A;
        height: 215px;
        position: relative;
        float: right;
    }
    #footer {
        width: 900px;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        background-color: #AEA03A;
        float: none;
        position: relative;
        height: 215px;
    } 

    #footer2 {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #AEA03A;
        padding-top: 30px;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
    }

    #address {
        height: 50px;
        width: 180px;
        background-color: #AEA03A;
        float: left;
        text-align: left;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #5A6219;
        line-height: 1.5em;
    }

    #contact {
        height: 130px;
        width: 180px;
        background-color: #AEA03A;
        float: left;
        text-align: left;
        margin-right: 180px;
        margin-left: 180px;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #5A6219;
        text-decoration: none;
        line-height: 18px;
    }

    #email {
        background-color: #AEA03A;
        height: 50px;
        width: 180px;
        float: right;
        text-align: left;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #5A6219;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .social {
        background-color: #AEA03A;
        height: 35px;
        width: 100%;
        float: right;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    #pinterest {
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        float: left;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        margin-left: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }



    .twitter {
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        float: left;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }


    .copywrite {
        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight: lighter;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        text-align: right;
        width: 300px;
        background-color: #AEA03A;
        float: right;
        height: 15px;
        color: #5A6219;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }

    .contactlink {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #5A6219;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .contactlink a {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #5A6219;
        text-decoration: none;
    }


    .contactlink:hover {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    h4 {
        color: #5A6219;
    }


    .indeximg {
        height: 100px;
        width: 900px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center top;
        background-image: url(../olivaimages/indeximg.png)
    }
    .indexwrap {
        height: 100%;
        width: 810px;
        padding-left: 90px;
    }

    #wrapper {
        min-height: 100%;
    }



    .clearfooter {
        height: 215px;
        clear: both;
    }
```

Comment: Please format your code properly and post a http://jsfiddle.net demo or remove the unnecessary CSS and HTML. This is not a code review service.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am new here and I thank in advance all the people who try to help.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#footerframe {
    background-color: #AEA03A;
    bottom: 0;
    float: right;
    height: 223px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but when I tried the absolute positioning for the footer it didn't work for other pages where the main content is stretched to a bigger size.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the footers 900px with 100% should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need implement a sticky footer technics by setting html,body height to 100% and
setting id#container as the following:

```
    html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%;
   }

  #container {
   height: auto !important; 
   min-height: 100%; 
   height: 100%;       
 }
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/PeEn2/1/)

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your help, but setting the padding to 0 messed up the whole design! Any other suggestion would be highly appreciated.